# Custom directive's scope model is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

**Background**: I have an Ionic app that displays a list of contacts by use of [`collection-repeat`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) (an Ionic improvement over Angular's `ng-repeat`). There's two toggle buttons at the top to decide which list of contacts to show. I've written a custom directive to display a contact's picture, title and subtitle.

HTML

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <div class="item item-avatar" collection-repeat="contact in viewing" force-refresh-images="true">
        <profile-or-initials ng-model="contact"></profile-or-initials>
        <h2>{{contact.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{contact.subtitle}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
app.directive('profileOrInitials', function($state) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class="profileOrInitials"></div>',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        var getInitials = function(user) {
          return user.title.substring(0, 2);

        };
        var process = function() {
          var image = scope.ngModel.feed_pic_url;
          var initials = getInitials(scope.ngModel);
          var html = '';

          if (image) {
            html = '<img src="' + image + '"></img>';
          } else {
            image = "http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/blue-image/blue-image-14.jpg";
            html = '<img src="' + image + '"></img><div class="initials">' + initials + '</div>';
          }

          element.html(html);
        };
        //var destroy = scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
        //  if (scope.ngModel) {
             process();
            //destroy();
          //}
        //});
      }
    };
  })
```

**Problem**: The directive's `ngModel` scope is `undefined` unless I add a `scope.$watch` function for it. Even further, if I call the `destroy` function on that watch, the directive stops working as well because when you click on the buttons the pictures aren't updated.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/t4opQdqr4VStpqP6MdQn.

Can anyone explain what is going here? I don't care about the actual solution. I just don't understand what is happening. My suspicion is that my directive's `link` function is running before `collection-repeat` and so at that point the model is undefined, but I tried lowering it's priority and it still doesn't work. ([collection-repeat has a priority of 1000](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/collectionRepeat.js#L95)).

Comment: I allways struggle with this also. The watch solution works for me. I dont see a ng-click for refreshing pictures though

Comment: The buttons at the top: "google contacts" and "facebook contacts" :)

Comment: Also no point using `ngModel` for something that doesn't need ngModel controller functionality. Just check `newValue` argument of `$watch` is defined and should work fine

Answer (score 0):

This is basically because of how `collection-repeat` works. It will create placeholders for the collection prior to rendering. If you try using `ng-repeat`, you will see that it works fine.

As a remedy/solution for using `collection-repeat`, you might consider using the following:

```
.directive('profileOrInitials', function($state) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      require: 'ngModel',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class="profileOrInitials"></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
        var getInitials = function(user) {
          return user.title.substring(0, 2);
        };
        model.$render = function() {
          m = model.$viewValue;
          var image = m.feed_pic_url;
          var initials = getInitials(m);
          var html = '';

          if (image) {
            html = '<img src="' + image + '"></img>';
          } else {
            image = "http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/blue-image/blue-image-14.jpg";
            html = '<img src="' + image + '"></img><div class="initials">' + initials + '</div>';
          }

          element.html(html);
        }
      }
    };
});
```

Notice that I have used `require: 'ngModel'` so that the model gets passed to the `link` function as the 4th argument. No need for explicitly declaring a scope.

Finally, `model.$render` will be called automatically when the model is set for the first time, which is when you click any of the buttons on the top of your example.

The value of the model may be retrieved using `model.$viewValue`

Comment: Also note that there may be a solution coping with this ng-model issue baked in to collection-repeat which I may not yet be aware of as I have rarely used ionic. But the provided solution will work regardless.